# What is causing this water on the drywall and how concerned should I be?

Tags: drywall, water

I noticed some light lines on the dry wall of one my internally facing walls.  Here is a picture of the water lines:

[image: Water streaks]

It's tough to tell from the picture (make sure to view in high resolution), but it is very light, and barely wet at all.  This is unlike other water damage I've seen that is result of a broken pipe.  I didn't even realize it was wet without touching it.  It's also barely visible on the drywall in the next room that shares the wall.  In this room, it is completely dry:

[image: Pointing to the drops]

Comment: What room is this in? Is the room near the kitchen or the bathroom? Is that an exterior wall?

Comment: It's an interior wall.  The side with less condensation is in a bathroom, the side with more condensation is not, but is close to a bathroom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What room is this in? 
Is the room near the kitchen or the bathroom? 
Is that an exterior wall?

I will see this in our bathroom when I forget to turn on the fan, or when I run the humidifier in a room with a cold exterior wall.

It's likely just condensation from cooking, a humidifier, the shower, etc. 
The drops are darker because as they roll down the wall they pick up dirt, dust, and grime (You never notice how dirty your walls really get).